# Can I disable indexes on MongoDB master that is used for writes only?

Tags: mongodb

We have an application that uses MongoDB for log keeping. We run a pair of machines in replica set. One machine is used for writes, another for reads (reports and lookups).

By looking at MongoDB docs I can see that there is a "buildIndexes" config option for replica set. 
Is there a downside of disabling indexes on a machine that is only used for writes? Would I need to "lock" a machine in a replica set to be always Master?

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need set buildIndexes option to false for write machine:

> When false, prevent secondary indexes
>   from being created on this member.
>   This is typically used on machines
>   that are pure "backup" machines that
>   are never queried. By not having the
>   secondary indexes, the member performs
>   less works on writes and requires less
>   ram. Note the _id index is still
>   created. Can only be set to false if
>   priority:0. It is rare to use this
>   option.

But in general i guess that for reports you need option to build indexes in background for both machines. But seems that mongodb doesn't support [background index building](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+as+a+Background+Operation) well for replica set.

[RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) build indexes in background by default (only a week ago was added option to build in sync ;)). I guess background indexes best solution for reports.